# How to prevent overlapping issue of custom labels in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I have created a path with x and y values of the chart and I have added the custom labels using the renderer.label, I am facing the issue of overlapping over the labels how can I handle that?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-xmjaeu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Could you please specify your issue? Do you mean the custom label overlap `xAxis.label`?